# ComboBox.Items.Clear unexpectedly reversing text in the input field

Tags: c#, combobox

When I type into the input field of combobox. it appears backwards. 
For example if I type 12345 it is displayed as 54321.
Try as I may, I cannot find this problem on web.
Commented code left to show some hacky efforts.

I suspect the Clear() method on Items is the problem, of course I cannot prove that.

All help, comments and criticisms welcome.

edit: Reduced code to bare minimum that illustrates issue.

````
```private void comboBoxSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        comboBoxSearch.Items.Clear();

    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

> if I type 12345 it is displayed as 54321

You have some event linked to your keypress that *resets the cursor*.

You type 1 => 1|

event fires and resets the cursor => |1

You type 2 => 2|1

event fires and resets the cursor => |21

You type 3 => 3|21

event fires...

Your event is a debugging mess that I cannot understand. Maybe clean that up, empty it, make sure typing then works and then add in line by line what you want to do and see where it fails.

Comment: I have edited the code to show bare minimum effect, and I believe it proves the Clear() method responsible.

Comment: If you need to call that method, I guess you have to get the cursor position before the call and set that position again after the call.